# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDependencyCheckerForDebug'

Tags: android

I don't know what happened. Last time my project runs smoothly (w/c happened last time) I haven't change anything except for I added another activity. Here is my problem [image]

I tried rebuilding and cleaning my proj but nothing happened I restarted my AS but no luck. Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidating caches and restart `Android Studio`. You can find it under file tab.
 [image: file]